# Shell/Bash command not found: browse

Tags: bash, shell

I have a bash script written back in 2011 which has this command among others:

```
browse $PWD
```

My script fails to run, thus I tried to execute just that command and I get this error:

```
zsh: command not found: browse
```

Searching on google gave me no results. Where is the underlying issue? Is my PC lacking some package or is this command no longer used and thus should be replaced?

For information I am using MacOS.

Comment: Btw.: `bash` != `zsh`

Comment: @JohnMayne : You are tagging the question by _bash_ and _shell_, but obviously run Zsh. For the error you get, you need to find _browse_ on your Mac (or install, if you don't have it anymore) and, like with any other program you are using, make sure that the directory where the program is located, is in your PATH.

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of `browse`. The closest thing I can think of is `browsh`, and despite being [very cool](https://github.com/browsh-org/browsh) (for watching youtube in the terminal...), I don't think it's as old as 2011.

There were no package matches for `browse` in `apt search` (ubuntu 18.04 LTS). I grepped `browse` in every *description* (ie `apt show`) for every matching package of `apt search browse` (which matches 'browser', and more than the just the package name), and none appeared to mention an executable / command actually called `browse`. Not conclusive, but often commands named differently to the package are mentioned there.

It may have been some other script / program associated with that script. Look in the same place that script came from.

Also, if you post the script it would help. It may be referring to a function or alias that isn't set correctly, or some conflict due to you perhaps running a `bash` script in the default MacOS shell (`ksh`). I wouldn't be suprised if it's an error with the script actually (or how you're running it). Have a look where else 'browse' occurs in the script.